# MySQL loading a tab-delimited file into a table with special characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to load a file into a MySQL table that has backslashes in it like this:

```
Fred          Los Angeles        I am Fred
Nick          Madison            Great Lakes Whoo
JOHN          San Diego          Hello world!\
Bob           NYC                Big apple
```

User JOHN put a `\` at the end of column 3.  When I load this into a table, MySQL is interpreting the backslash as some kind of line continuation and concatenating Row 3, Col 3) with (Row 4, Col1).

I can't just copy and paste to fix it since there are millions of rows like this with backslashes in various places causing havoc.

What is the proper way to load a tab-delimited file into a MySQL table with backslashes? Should I be enclosing each (column) field in quotes?  Should I write a parser that removes special characters?

Comment: I would write a parser to handle the special characters.  Enclosing the field in quotes might not work if the data has quotes.

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify `ESCAPED BY` option when loading your file. In the following example I'm assuming your fields are divided by tab (which is default behavior) and file is located on clients host:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/my.txt' INTO TABLE t
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\b';
```

Answer (score 4):

### How to tame backslashes in mysql load data infile tool:

**Step 1, create your table:**

```
mysql> create table penguin (id int primary key, chucknorris VARCHAR(4000));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Step 2, create your file to import and put this data in there.**

```
1   aliens are on route
2   scramble the nimitz\
3   \its species 8472
4   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
5   Bonus characters:!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\|}{;'":/.?>,< anything but tab
```

**Step 3, insert into your table:**

```
mysql> load data local infile '/home/el/foo/textfile.txt' into table penguin 
       fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' 
       (@col1, @col2) set id=@col1, chucknorris=@col2;
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1
```

**Step 4, and of course, it causes this weird output:**

```
mysql> select * from penguin;
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | chucknorris                                                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | aliens are on route                                             |
|  2 | scramble the nimitz
3                                           |
|  4 | \\\\\\\\\                                                       |
|  5 | Bonus characters:!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]|}{;'":/.?>,< anything but tab |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Step 5, analyze the warning:**

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+------------------------------------- ------------------+
| Warning | 1262 | Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there |
|         |      | were input columns                                     |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Step 6, think about exactly what went wrong:**

The backslash to the left of `nimitz` caused the mysql load data parser to concatenate the end of line 2 with the beginning of line 3.  Then it bumped up against a tab and put 'scramble the nimitz\n3 into row 2.

The rest of row 3 is skipped because the extra words `its species 8472` do not fit anywhere, it produces the warning you see above.

Row 4 had 18 backslashes, so there is no problem, and shows up as 9 backslahes because each was escaped.  Had there been an odd number, the error on row 2 would have happened to row 4.

The bonus characters on row 5 came through normally. Everything is allowed except tab.

**Step 7, reset penguin:**

```
mysql> delete from penguin;
```

**Step 8, load into your table with the `fields escaped by` clause:**

```
mysql> load data local infile '/home/el/foo/textfile.txt' into table penguin 
       fields terminated by '\t' escaped by '\b' 
       lines terminated by '\n' (@col1, @col2) set id=@col1, 
       chucknorris=@col2;

Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Step 9, select from your table, interpret the results:**

```
mysql> select * from penguin;
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | chucknorris                                                      |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | aliens are on route                                              |
|  2 | scramble the nimitz\                                             |
|  3 | \its species 8472                                                |
|  4 | \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\                                               |
|  5 | Bonus characters:!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\|}{;'":/.?>,< anything but tab |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And now everything is as we expect.  The backslash at the end of line 2 does not escape the newline.  The backslash before `i` on row 3 doesn't do anything.  The 18 backslashes on row 4 are not escaped.  And the bonus characters come through ok.